# WHMCS is being hacked by {php} and Eval base64 code through tickets

Tags: php, apache, smarty, whmcs, mod-security2

WHMCS uses Smarty for it's template system, though a great template system it has a flaw, the `{php}` tags. These tags allow smarty to interpret PHP code directly in the template, or in this case through the ticket system when a new ticket is created. This hack happens all the time to WHMCS systems, you can try blocking the code in WHMCS through block text option in configuration. But most of the time this doesn't work.

What happens is that WHMCS accepts the ticket and the hacker added the following to the ticket message:

```
{php}eval(base64_decode(encoded message));{\php}
```

So smarty sees the `{php}` part and immediately let's PHP run that command. So it first decodes the PHP encoded in base64. This will bring out some PHP function/script that the hacker is trying to run.

Then eval takes over and actually evaluates the PHP code and runs it on server side.

A lot of hackers get in this way, they run codes that they know will work in WHMCS that then grab Database information and echo it to a file. Then they just grab this file through the browser URL and get the information they wanted.

This works on only some WHMCS install's, though WHMCS says that the most recent version doesn't allow this and {php} is disabled in Smarty, at times the hacker's do find a way to get around that and `eval` their code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a very simple hack to fix using mod_security. First off find where your mod_security config file is located, this all depends on your install of mod_security and OS but it's normally called `modsec.conf` or `modsec2.conf`, sometimes `security.conf` but very seldom.

You can find it using the `locate` command, if installed, on most linux systems.

```
sudo updatedb
locate modsec.conf
or
locate modsec2.conf
```

If you don't have `locate` your going to need to go to the `/` directory and just run `find`, this will take some time but sometimes panels install it in weird places not just in `/etc`.

```
cd /
find . -type f -iname 'modsec*.conf'
```

Either way will work to find the config file. Once found use your favorite editor to edit the file and go to the very bottom and add the following:

```
SecRuleEngine On    
SecRule ARGS {php} "severity:4,log,deny"
SecRule ARGS eval "severity:4,log,deny"
SecRule ARGS base64_decode "severity:4,log,deny"
```

Basically your telling it to filter arguments in `GET` and `POST`. That's it, restart apache now:

```
CentOS:
service httpd restart

Ubuntu:
service apache2 restart
```

Now you might be thinking this will block you from using those commands in scripts, not at all. That only blocks those words from being sent over `GET` or `POST`. If someone tries they get a `Not Acceptable` error and it just doesn't work at all.

This saves you from having to block a bunch of IP's from your firewall or WHMCS and potential customer's.

Answer (score 2):

[There's a flag in the Smarty config to enable/disable this](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.tpl), and it should be ***off*** by default.

If using `{php}` tags is required by WHMCS, then they are [to put it as politely as possible] incredibly f*cking retarded and should get out of the business of making billing, or any other software.

Edit: Yup, [right here in their docs](http://docs.whmcs.com/Template_Syntax#Using_PHP_Code_within_Templates). "Hey look! We turned on this *super* giant security hole just for you!"

You might want to grep through your template files to find any usages of these `{php}` tags as it will indicate any functionality you'll be losing by plugging this gaping hole in security.

Comment: Correct, as I stated below, you can do this but sometimes it doesn't work and the eval still gets through. I know this for a fact as we use WHMCS and we had it turned off for ages and were still getting some tickets through. Not as many as before but still they came through. The best bet is to use modsec to block it entirely, that way it never even gets to the PHP interpreter. That is the most secure way to block it.